# how to select date time step by 60 second from first value to last value in table

Tags: sql-server, query, select, group-by

I want to add 60 seconds to the date value from the first date and return the data if it exists in that interval
like this

| datetime | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-02 12:20:1 | 5 |
| 2021-05-02 12:20:15 | 8 |
| 2021-05-02 12:20:26 | 12 |
| 2021-05-02 12:21:1 | 63 |
| 2021-05-02 12:21:23 | 90 |
| 2021-05-02 12:21:12 | 73 |
| 2021-05-02 12:22:3 | 39 |
| 2021-05-02 12:23:12 | 3 |
| 2021-05-02 12:28:23 | 74 |
| 2021-05-02 12:28:26 | 38 |
| 2021-05-02 12:28:26 | 72 |
| 2021-05-02 12:28:28 | 12 |
| 2021-05-02 12:28:30 | 69 |

RESULT like :

| datetime | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-02 12:20:1 | 5 |
| 2021-05-02 12:21:1 | 63 |
| 2021-05-02 12:22:3 | 39 |
| 2021-05-02 12:23:12 | 3 |
| 2021-05-02 12:28:23 | 74 |

I try by this code But I did not get the right Result

```
        WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datetime ORDER BY DATETIME)-  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dateadd(second,60,datetime) ORDER BY DATETIME) as g
    FROM Inputs
                    )
                SELECT DateTime
                    FROM cte
                    group by g
```

Comment: Can you construct a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with your tables and data - also, a more detailled explanation of your requirement would also help! Some of the data points aren't even real times!

Comment: Take a look at [mcve] and add the requisite details to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can truncate the date to the minute and partition by that value

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, t.datetime), 0)
        ORDER BY t.datetime) AS rn
    FROM YourTable t
)
SELECT
  datetime,
  value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: HOW TO PARTITION BY 15 MINUTE OR 10 MINUTE?

Comment: `DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, t.datetime) / 15 * 15, 0)`